# url rewrite deosnt access my css and images? why

Tags: css, image, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have this rewrite rule for my urls, it deosnt seem to acess the css and images, why? :))

orginal url its working:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/viewprofile.php?user=muna
```

rewrited url, this deosnt work:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/user/muna
```

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /viewprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

my css files are stored in /css folder and images in the /images folder

Comment: How are you linking to your css and images?

Comment: i include my header on the top of my page, which has all the css files in the header i.e. css/style.css and css/base.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry guys, i found the solution, im gonna answer this question just for future reference for other stackoverflowers, basically when you do a rewrite on any url just make sure when your linking to javascripts, css or images the right way for example:

if before you had:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css"></link>
```

then change to this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/demo.css"></link>
```

quote the extra `/` before css folder name. thanks hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

or you can add some rules, and then you may don't need change the html code.

RewriteRule ^user/css/(.*)$ /css/$1 [L]

Comment: but is that going to work, on all urls, remember if people rewrite two urls, if you know what i mean, plus it deosnt work